# Sending multiple variables with url

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to do a call to my REST service to create a supplier. I need the `itemCode` of the supplied item and the `username` that wants to create it. Right now, i am call it like this:

```
th:href="@{/api/supplier/getSupplierViewItem/{username}(username = ${username})/{itemCode}(itemCode = ${item.itemCode})}
```

Then, my controller should get that petition:

```
    @GetMapping("/getSupplierViewItem/{username:.+}/{itemCode:.+}")
    public String getSupplierViewwithItem(@PathVariable("username")String username, @PathVariable("itemCode") String itemCode, ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        model.addAttribute("itemCode", itemCode);
        return "createSupplier";
    }
```

However, when I try it, I get this following petition:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/supplier/getSupplierViewItem/%7Busername%7D(username%20=%20$%7Busername%7D)/01231
```

Basically, instead of the value of username, I´m getting

```
{username}(username = ${username})
```

Which is the best way to send both parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for your url is:

```
th:href="@{/api/supplier/getSupplierViewItem/{username}/{itemCode}(username=${username},itemCode=${item.itemCode})}"
```

See the [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters) for multiple parameters.